# Preloaded data in Reactive form disappear with ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError after modal is closed

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project there is a sidenav, where one of the links calls my problematic component with some input data.

Here is my TS:

```
@Input() data: MyData;
myModal: BsModalRef;
editForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        inOne: [this.data.one, [Validators.required]],
        inTwo: [this.data.two, [Validators.required]]
    });
}

showModal() {
    const config: ModalOptions = {
        initialState: {
            message: 'Some dynamic tip message'
        }
    };
    this.myModal = this.modalService.show(MyModalComponent, config);
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="editForm.valid && save()">
    <h3>SIMPLE MODE</h3>
    <app-text-input 
        [formControl]="editForm.controls['inOne']" [type]="'number'">
    </app-text-input>
    <app-text-input 
        [formControl]="editForm.controls['inTwo']" [type]="'number'">
    </app-text-input>
    
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)="showModal()">Tip</button>
</form>
```

app-text-input

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input 
        [class.is-invalid]='ngControl.touched && ngControl.invalid' 
        type={{type}} 
        class="form-control"
        [formControl]="ngControl.control" 
        placeholder={{label}}"
    >
    <!-- some validators -->
</div>
```

This code works fine.
Any time I call my view from sidenav I see all the preloaded data (check `ngOnInit`). A problem comes after I interact with `myModal`. When I close it I still see my data in inputs. But when I go to another sidenav page and turn back - I miss all my pre-loaded data.
In console:

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'ng-valid': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.mjs:6733:1)
    at bindingUpdated (core.mjs:12710:1)
    at checkStylingProperty (core.mjs:16451:1)
    at ɵɵclassProp (core.mjs:16359:1)
    at NgControlStatus_HostBindings (forms.mjs:1367:1)
    at processHostBindingOpCodes (core.mjs:9251:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9530:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9534:1)
```

I've tried to fix this error by implementation of

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

The error goes, but I still miss my preloaded data. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to understand why this problem happened, but finally it was because of my `save()` function where I interact with values from all inputs.

So the solution was to change a logic inside `(ngSubmit)` from:

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="editForm.valid && save()">
```

To:

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="editForm.valid ? save() : null">
```

Now everything is working as I was expecting.